# Can I safely run SpecFlow tests using xUnit test runner, expecting full support?

Tags: specflow, .net-6.0

Specflow test runner [does not support .Net 6](https://specflow.org/using-specflow/the-retirement-of-specflow-runner/). This makes me wonder whether SpecFlow is a good technology to use for end-to-end tests in .Net. I would not like to invest a lot of time in building end-to-end tests only to find out that in the near future the integration breaks and Specflow is no longer supported in .Net.

Can I safely use a different test runner (say, nUnit or xUnit)? Can I expeting SpecFlow to be supported in future .Net releases? I know nobody has a crystal ball, but I wanted to know if this is considered the "new standard" for running SpecFlow tests in .Net.

Answer (score 2):

[SpecFlow supports the major unit test providers.](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Unit-Test-Providers.html). You can [migrate from SpecFlow+Runner](https://%5BSpecFlow%20supports%20the%20major%20unit%20test%20providers.%5D(https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Unit-Test-Providers.html).%20There%20is%20a) to any of those providers.

The [retirement of SpecFlow+Runner](https://specflow.org/using-specflow/the-retirement-of-specflow-runner/) was announced in January 2022:

> We have had numerous queries regarding the support of .NET 6 for SpecFlow+ Runner. Sadly, we must let you all know that we will be discontinuing any further development on SpecFlow+ Runner, with version 3.9.31 being the last version of the SpecFlow+ Runner.
>
> ... To be able to achieve our goals, we need to be more focused and get rid of things that would hinder us in our progress. ... Unfortunately, SpecFlow+ Runner is one of the projects that is hindering us in innovating. Developing a test-runner that integrates tightly in the .NET ecosystem has become more complicated in the last few years. Adding support for a new .NET version (which happens every year) is a fair amount of work for multiple developers.

Currently SpecFlow supports the following unit test providers (or test runners):

- MS Test
- NUnit
- xUnit

Since the unit test providers above handle integration with the Visual Studio test runner, they will have long term support. Choose whichever one suits your needs.

See the [SpecFlow+Runner docs](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/) for more information.